# .Net core 6 docker containers are not working

Tags: .net, docker, containers

[enter image description here][1]The indivual containers are not starting on the dockers desktop through .Net Core 6 in the visual studio. How could I handle it?[enter image description here][2]

Commands to build and run

```
PS C:\Projects\PlatformService> docker --version 
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086 
PS C:\Projects\PlatformService> docker build -t nilna/platformservice 
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument. 
See 'docker build --help'. 

Usage: docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | - 

Build an image from a Dockerfile 
PS C:\Projects\PlatformService> docker run -d -p 8080:80 nilna/platformservice 
3c8eaf8b868edfbf1e507d818c1aed4eb5cbe97a5e55c85c74e873dda267f6bc 
PS C:\Projects\PlatformService>
```

Comment: Your error message complains that it can't find `PlarformService.dll` with an 'r'. I suspect the error message is not from a docker image generated by the dockerfile you show. Also, please post your information as text and not as images.

Comment: I am trying those still coming PlarformService.dll

Comment: Your build fails. It should be `docker build -t nilna/platformservice .` (the period at the end tells docker that the build context is the current directory)

Comment: now it works! Thank yo so much!!

Comment: please put your images again. thanks